# Update a single cell MySQL PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, sql-update

I am trying to update a single cell and I don't know why but each time I try I got this error:  `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'partcipateInLolProject' in 'field list'`

Here is the PHP code:

```
    if(!isset($args['id'], $args['status'])){
      return $response->withStatus(400)->withHeader('Location', $this->router->pathFor('list-online-contacts-page'));
    }

    $id = $args["id"];
    $status = $args['status'];

    $prep = $this->db->prepare("UPDATE `onlineinscription` SET `partcipateInLolProject` = :status WHERE `id` = :id");

    $prep -> bindParam(':status', $status);
    $prep -> bindParam(':id', $id);
    $prep -> execute();
```

Those args are checked earlier by regex and are both 1 to 5 number long integer. When I run the exact same query on my mysql prompt it work like a charm, here is the test query : 
 `UPDATE onlineinscription SET participateInLolProject = 1 WHERE id = 104`
I checked the two variables (status and id) before binding them and they are as expected. The MySQL credentials are fine, on the right server/DB. The db is created earlier like this:

```
    $db = $c->get('settings')['db'];
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $db['host'] . ";dbname=" . $db['dbname'], $db['user'], $db['pass'], array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8'));
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $pdo;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spot the difference:

```
$prep = $this->db->prepare("[..snip..] `partcipateInLolProject` = :status WHERE `id` = :id");
                                            ^----

UPDATE onlineinscription SET participateInLolProject = 1 WHERE id = 104
                                 ^---
```

So... read the error message more closely next time?

Comment: In fact I used to had the same problem earlier so I thought it was the same, lol I'm so stupid, thanks for answer it work like a charm now

Comment: Yeah... I've run into these sorts of walls way more times than I'd care to admit. Everyone's been there/done that.

Comment: Main mistake is to think that you're smarter than the computer. We were long ago relegated to merely being the means by which computers propagate themselves.